# I want to Add Avatar at my joomla site but can't find the right solution please help me

Tags: joomla3.0, avatar, avatar-generation

Hello friends i need help For my joomla site & i like to add Avatar builder for making profile picture of users and for comics purpose. It may be Free Or paid it may contain various characters. Create and customize an avatar to look just like users or anyone users want it to be! select your eyes, hair and go-to outfit please help me and give me right solution for my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes friend, i had a similar requirement where i had to add avatar to a joomla3.2 articles which registered users can manage.

I found a free Joomla extension which work wonderfully for me.
Avatar Builder for Joomla 3.2. Try it out and let me know whether this is working for you.
http://avatarbuilder.technoscore.net/

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tried it and it works well. here is the extension on Joomla Extensions Market. 

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/personal-layout/27052. But how to add new characters to the original avatar builder and is there a way I could add my profile image as an option to this ???